# icon bar customisation in html and css

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to customise the following icon bar (as shown in w3schools) - code pasted below along with link, to display like the image shown. The icons need to have text right underneath them (labels). This is NOT trivial as you'll see if you continue to read the description of the problem. 
Furthermore, I'd like to add hover-over text to these icons, as shown.

[image]

Any solutions/suggestions appreciated.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_icon_bar_h

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.icon-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bar a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}

.active {
    background-color: #44444 !important;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="signup.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> 
  <a href="challenges.php"><i class="fa fa-mortar-board"></i></a> 
  <a href="login.php"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> 
  <a href="series.php"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the image shown, the icon bar is placed over a green background image. I would like the text to appear directly underneath, and for there also to be hover-over text to appear.

I have tried the below, but it is incredibly difficult to get the layout correct. Is there a better way?

```
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="signup.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> 
  <a href="challenges.php"><i class="fa fa-mortar-board"></i></a> 
  <a href="login.php"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> 
  <a href="series.php"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>

</div>
<br>
<br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>    
    <br><br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>    
    <br>
    <p><font color="white">Topic1  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                    Topic2      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                   Topic3        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                Topic4</font></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
```

Furthermore, a design flaw with adding text that way is on mobile sites the formatting will be entirely lost. see image below.

[image]

Any ideas to most effectively do this would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for the w3 school code 
I just changed the way of writing the icon and the text .

its not possible to look the iconbar same way in all screen size either put dropdown button or vertical display ,I have written that for vertical display ,. I havent changed padding . Since i dont know much what you want

I can help you with bootstrap if you want in bootstrap i think that will be easy for you .

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-
  awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
     body {margin:0;}
    .icon-bar {
       width: 100%;
       background-color: #555;
       overflow: auto;
     }

    .icon-bar a {
       float: left;
       width: 20%;
       text-align: center;
       padding: 12px 0;
       transition: all 0.3s ease;
       color: white;
       font-size: 36px;
    } 

    .icon-bar a:hover {
       background-color: #000;
      }

    .icon-bar a{
       text-decoration:none;

    }

   .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
    }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .icon-bar a {
    width:100% !important;
   }
}

  </style>
  <body>

 <div class="icon-bar">
   <a class="active" href="#">
   <ul style="list-style:none">
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i></li>
    <li>home</li>
  </ul>
  </a> 
  <a href="#">
     <ul style="list-style:none" class="menu_ul">
      <li><i class="fa fa-search"></i></li>
      <li>search</li>
     </ul>
 </a> 
  <a href="#">
    <ul style="list-style:none" class="menu_ul">
      <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></li>
      <li>mail</li>
   </ul>
  </a> 
  <a href="#">
     <ul style="list-style:none" class="menu_ul">
       <li><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></li>
       <li>web</li>
    </ul>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <ul style="list-style:none" class="menu_ul">
    <li><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></li>
    <li>delete</li>
   </ul></a> 
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: one issue with this, as I mentioned in my q, is mobile view. It would squash the text. How do you make the whole thing smaller (text of the text and the icons?)

Comment: And the hover text is missing - are you able to add the above for me to accept your answer? (so to make it all smaller, remove the underline from the link of text, and to add the hover information) as mentioned in the original question. Thanks V much

Comment: Thanks for accepting .. Do you want same design in mobile screen  or have dopdown in mobile screen for menu ??? .. ya that is missing hover thing i missed that ... i am adding that

Comment: please check https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdydmK?editors=1010 and tell if you want different from this

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.icon-bar{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-bar a {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

This will affect all the a tags of .icon-bar class.

Also here's some documentation on how display flex works, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This is interesting but doesn't answer the question as I'm still not sure what to try to get the icons looking like I've shown in the image uploaded. I want the icons and text neatly/closely under neath each icon as a navigation bar